# Get access to xml parts of a CLOSED excel workbook - how

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I am self-learning how to manipulate the openXML elements of Excel files from within Excel using VBA.

I have VBA code that will allow me to create a CustomXMLPart, add a CustomXMLPart and read/update the 'contents' (attributes) of these.

The code I have, works only on the ActiveWorkbook.
This means that the particular Excel file has to be open.

Is it possible to gain access to the CustomXMLParts of a CLOSED Excel workbook from within VBA and how would I do this?
I know that these are contained in a zip archive but whilst there is a specific folder for them, there isn't a specific 'file' with an .XML extension to 'load'.

The general approach and perhaps simple specific code examples would be most helpful to get me going please.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid opening the file? Too heavy with a lot of dynamic content like macros?...

Comment: Yes the files I will be working with are unknown and may contain WorkBook_Open events which I don't really want to become involved with.

Comment: If you add CustomXMLPart into workbook, save it, and then open as .zip archive, you can find `customXml` folder with `item1.xml` file containing added content. Tested on Excel 2010 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question this should help you:

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
[ ... do your stuff with WB ... ]
WB.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The file will be open, but it will be fast because it's open read only (much faster than with write permission) and there is no UI update (often the slowest part of any VBA macro).

Comment: Thank you for your interest. The files I will be working on are unknown and may contain 'start-up' macros. Thank you also for your input. I am OK with VBA, but I note your comments about speed.  I am particularly interested in accessing and manipulating the XLM file which resides outside the workbook.

Comment: If you disable the events the macros are not executed: `Application.EnableEvents = False / Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FileName) / Application.EnableEvents = True`